# Discrete Math Proof of Inequalities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-explanation

In the following completed proof, in the highlighted steps, it seems as though the proof is defending its claim by showing that $2(\sqrt{k+2}-1) < (\text{the lower highlighted part in the proof})$. Shouldn't it be showing instead that $2(\sqrt{k+2}-1) \ge (\text{the lower highlighted part in the proof})$, in order for the proof to be true? Why or why not?

[image]

Why I think this:

Because the P(k+1) we are trying to show, has the left side greater than the right side.

The rest of the work needs to also try to show that the right side(which is being manipulated to try and look like the right side of the P(k+1) inequality) is less than the original P(k+1) inequality's right side, SO THAT the left side of the P(k+1) inequality will always be bigger.

Comment: Why do you think it should be the other way? It looks like they are trying to prove a lower bound, not an upper bound.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Because the ( k+1) we are trying to show, has the left side greater than the right side. The rest of the work needs to also try to show that the right side(which is being manipulated to try and look like the right side of the (k+1) inequality) is less than the original (k+1) inequality's right side, SO THAT  the left side of the (k+1) inequality will always be bigger.

Comment: @AlexisOlson the above.

Comment: Yes, the left side is greater than the right side. That's exactly what is shown. I still don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @AlexisOlson how did they convert the lower highlighted lines that I have to to the upper highlighted line. I don't understand why it can be changed to each other just because there is a $>1$ near the end of the proof?

Comment: Do you agree that if $a > 1$ and $b > 0$, then $a b > b$?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes, how does that apply here to adding and subtracting?

Comment: I can't resist mentioning that since $1/\sqrt {a}>\int_a^{a+1}(1/\sqrt x)dx$ for $a\geq 1,$  we have , by summing from $a=1$ to $a=n,$ that $\sum_{a=1}^n(1/\sqrt a)>$ $\int_1^{n+1}(1/\sqrt x)dx=2(\sqrt {n+1}-1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've agreed that if $a > 1$ and $b>0$, the $ab > b$.

Now lets pick particular $a$ and $b$:

$$a = \sqrt{\frac{4k^2 + 12 k + 9}{4k^2 + 12 k + 8}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
b = 2\sqrt{k+2}.$$

Thus

$$ab = 2 \sqrt{\frac{4k^2 + 12 k + 9}{4k^2 + 12 k + 8}}\sqrt{k+2} > 2\sqrt{k+2} = b.$$

Therefore $ab - 2 > b - 2$ implies

$$2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{4k^2 + 12 k + 9}{4k^2 + 12 k + 8}}\sqrt{k+2}\right) - 2 > 2\sqrt{k+2} - 2 = 2\left(\sqrt{k+2}-1\right).$$

Comment: Yes, but what is preventing AB from being greater than 'sum of 1/sqrt(i) from i=1 to k+1'(lets call this X) as is depicted in the left most part of OP? we only prove that AB > B but we haven't proved what the upper limit on AB is. We havent proved that X>AB?

Comment: @SajSeesSound That follows from all of the previous steps. We already had $X > ab - 2$ and are now showing $X > b - 2$.

Comment: @AlexisOlsen So after some algebra, we can 'suppose' that X>ab-2 and we want to get ab-2 into the form b-2, which is why we also show that ab-2 > b-2. Now since we already know that X> ab-2 , we have now proven that X>b-2 , and therefore can conclude that X>b-2?

Comment: @SajSeesSound We aren't "supposing" it. It is shown through a series of steps (using the induction hypothesis and some algebra.). But yes, $X > ab-2$ and $ab - 2 > b - 2$ implies $X > b-2$.

Comment: Okay, my entire confusion was in the fact that  I thought we were starting from b-2 from deduction, and then showing that ab-2> b-2 but absent of the fact that that X>ab-2 had also been deduced. Thanks